# Catching an error in an async function in Node/Express

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

Is there any way to catch an error that occurs in an async callback after an Express `next()` or `res.send()` has been called from middleware or a route handler?  Consider the following code:

```
app.use('/throw-error', (req, res) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    throw new Error('Async error causes thread death')
  }, 500)

  res.send('This thread is going to die...')
})
```

It will execute and send "This thread is going to die..." to the browser.  It will also, a half second later, crash that Node thread it is running in.  If you happen to be running an app that uses Node's `cluster` module, maybe it launches a new thread, but it died nonetheless.  You might see something like this in your logs:

```
::1 [2019-07-17T18:54:55.142Z] - [71700] 4.740 ms "GET /throw-error" 200 -
/Users/moryl/Projects/crashtest/express.js:66
      throw new Error('Async error causes thread death')
      ^

Error: Async error causes thread death
    at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/Users/moryl/Projects/InSight/sources/server/config/express.js:66:13)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
```

That thread is now dead.

My question is, **how the heck do you handle a (*possibly unknown*) async error that is outside the scope of a normal request**, whether by design or through bad code?  How do I prevent the thread from dying?

*I don't want to be told that I shouldn't do this kind of stuff in async calls to begin with.  I know this.  I'm trying to write defensive code to catch "bad stuff" written by others.*

Comment: I think you need to be more specific with _"a weird async error"_, are you talking about an error that's random / intermittent and hard to trace? Or are you talking about an expected error that you know about? The latter is fairly simple...

Comment: @James I'm talking about unknown errors.  I'm not trying to debug some error.  I can do that easily enough.  I'm trying to make such bugs not be fatal to the thread when they are uncovered.  I will remove the word "weird" from the question if that lessens the confusion.

Comment: There aren't that many sources for "unknown errors". Most libraries (e.g. socket.io) provide an error event, and you should listen to that.

Comment: @MichaelOryl If we are talking about _expected_ errors e.g. a DB connection failure or a missing file etc. then naturally you want to handle these, because we understand that these _may_ happen. If we are talking about _unexpected_ errors, then actually, it's more often than not safer to let the app crash because it's something we didn't expect and therefore cannot guarantee the state of the app.

Comment: @James No, not talking about expected errors, either.  APIs change.  Lots of the code in this app was written by an outside firm - poorly, at times.  New problems pop up when the data fed into the system changes.  I'm trying to detect such issues and handle them more gracefully. The link at the end of this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57082917/1480995) will allow me to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, how the heck do you handle an async error that is outside the scope of a normal request, whether by design ...

You still want to handle errors in asynchronous code, even if it was *fired and forgotten by design*. Add a `try { } catch { }` or `.catch` to every independent task. With asynchronous code, Promises and `async` / `await`help you (as they group independent callbacks into tasks, and you can handle errors per task then):

```
const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function fireAndForgetThis() {
  await timer(500);
  throw new Error('Async error doesn't cause thread death, because its handled properly')
}

 fireAndForgetThis()
   .catch(console.error); // But always "handle" errors
```

> ... or through bad code?

Fix bad code.

> How do I prevent the thread from dying?

That's not the thing you want to prevent. If an error occurs, and was not handled, your application gets into an unplaned state. Continuing execution might create even more problems. You don't want that. You want to prevent the unhandled rejection / unhandled error itself (by handling it properly).

---

For sure there are cases you can't handle, e.g. if the connection to the backing database goes down. In that case, NodeJS crashes, causes the monitoring to wake up DevOps that get the database back running. Crashing is also a form of *handling the error ;)*

---

If you read this far, and you still want to handle unhandled errors, don't. Okay well, you probably have your reasons, [there you go](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception).

Comment: The last link in your answer is actually useful.  The rest was a combination of things I already knew (and didn't ask about) and snark.  I know how to handle this kind of thing in code we write, and how to fix bad code code that gets exposed through errors that show in the logs.  The question was how to handle the situation more generically since we have APIs that change and create new issues, and we have inherited thousands of lines of code from an outside firm.  Your last link pointing to the event handler will at least allow us to log such events clearly.  Thanks.

Comment: No, that's not snark, at least it is not intended to be snarky. Thats a necessary warning. In 99% of the cases you want to handle your errors properly.

Answer (score 3):

This has been documented in `express` [error handling doc](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html):

> You **must catch errors that occur in asynchronous code invoked by route
>   handlers** or middleware and pass them to Express for processing. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
>   setTimeout(function () {
>     try {
>       throw new Error('BROKEN')
>     } catch (err) {
>       next(err)
>     }
>   }, 100)
> })
> ```
>
> The above example uses a **try...catch block to catch errors** in the
>   asynchronous code and pass them to Express. **If the try...catch block
>   were omitted, Express would not catch the error since it is not part
>   of the synchronous handler code.**

So, basically you need to `try..catch` the route. (the examples are basically same, mother of coincidence)

Comment: Unless you introduce your own error handler which _doesn't_ try to send an error response, calling `next` would inadvertently just result in a different error because the response has already been sent.

Comment: I was not asking how to properly catch an error inside the code.  The setTimeout() was simply an example that would cause an async error that would simulate the problem.  This answer doesn't address the question(s).  Thanks, though.